# Semantical Error] line 0, col 57 near Doctrine and Zend 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, doctrine

I have this Query :

```
$dql = "SELECT g FROM \Synchro\Entity\Geographicalarea g WHERE g.nameGeographicalArea=".$this->GetSQLValueString($nameGeographicalArea,"text")." AND g.codeGeo='".$codeGeo."' ";
```

when i run i get This Error:

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 57 near
>   'nameGeographicalArea='Alsace'': Error: Class
>   Synchro\Entity\Geographicalarea has no field or association named
>   nameGeographicalArea

How can i resolve that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Pls add your Entity into the question.

Comment: You need to give more detail of your context. At least your entity class.

Comment: Add more details to your question please. No one will be able to help you like this...